# Tensorflow on Colab v/s Local. Code gives error on colab (expected) but runs fine locally

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0, loss-function

I was following the DeepLearning.AI course on coursera when I noticed that the given notebook for a certain experiment gave errors on Colab (as it apparently should) but on local it runs regardless.

- The data set is fashion MNIST
- there are 10 class labels, the experiment was to change the number of neurons in the final layer from 10 to 5.
- This is the code

```
fmnist = tf.keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(training_images, training_labels) ,  (test_images, test_labels) = fmnist.load_data()

training_images = training_images/255.0
test_images = test_images/255.0

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation=tf.nn.relu),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax) # Try experimenting with this layer
                                  ])

model.compile(optimizer = 'adam',
              loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics = ['accuracy'])

model.fit(training_images, training_labels, epochs=5)

model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)

classifications = model.predict(test_images)

print(classifications[0])
print(test_labels[0])
```

- on Colab, changing it to 5 gives the following error message :
  "Received a label value of 9 which is outside the valid range of [0, 5).  Label values: 0 2 0 3 4 9 6 8 8 7 7 5 9 5 7 9 7 4 2 5 8 5 4 4 4 1 9 7 9 1 5 7"
- Locally it runs regardless..
  [local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iluZ6.png)

Can someone explain why this happens? shouldn't the loss function detect it just the same..

both colab and local runs on tensorflow 2.12.0

I was running the code from the VSC. It ran code it shouldn't have. On Collab it gives the error as expected...